# FireFox error in HTML5 audio source

Tags: html, firefox

I have an HTML5 audio source defined as follows:

```
 <audio>
    <source src="../audio/segment.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <source src="../audio/segment.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

The .mp3 is there for other browsers, and is expected to fail.  The .wav file used to work without issue, but now does not.  I have tried going over FF change logs and havent found anything in the latest releases.  I am using FF 20 on Windows, and the error i receive now is:

```
"Media resource http://website.com/segment.wav could not be decoded"
```

If i throw the .wav URL in to the address bar FF will play the file without issue.

Comment: A valid issue, but I'm curious why one would use a WAV in the first place? Is it not a huge waste of resources?

Comment: the wave is only 5kb larger than the .mp3, so not really.

Comment: The problem is depending on the actual wav file. Can you give us a link to it.

Answer (score 4):

Note that at time of writing FireFox won't play 24bit .wav files.  Convert them to 16 bit and they'll be happy.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this exact situation: the WAV file plays when loaded directly in Firefox, but not in an `<audio>` element. The problem for me was that the 44-byte header of my WAV files was invalid. After ensuring that the file length, byte rate, and block align were correct, I was able to play them just fine.

Here's the description of the WAV header specification that I used: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/.

Comment: Having same issue. How did you changed the headers and ensured that they are correct